# How do I disable -u interpreter option in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, nose

I am configuring PyCharm to use remote python interpreter. PyCharm seems to execute the interpreter with -u option, and I can't find a way to disable that. The reason I need it disabled is that I am running `nosetests` command, so I get this:

```
ssh://xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22/path/to/bin/nosetests -s -a M_4439 -u /path/to/test_elf.py

Usage: nosetests [options]

nosetests: error: no such option: -u

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I looked around, and could not find where `-u` is set. I checked:

- Run -> Edit configurations. I have my options there: `-s -a M_4439`
- Settings -> Project interpreter

Where is `-u` set?

Comment: In edit configuration, did you look under Default-->Python tests-->Nosetests?

Comment: Just looked, there was nothing there. Your comment prompted me to look more. Apparently, PyCharm has its helper script to run nose tests. I configured the interpreter to be remote python and now I get this (which is what I need): `ssh://xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22/path/to/bin/python -u /path/to/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/noserunner.py /path/to/test_elf.py
`. Now I just need to figure out pre-test scripts that are usually sourced from `.bashrc`, and I am good to go.Thanks.

Comment: Can't figure out how to source a bash script before noserunner.py is executed (source from the same shell in which the tests will be executed)

Comment: Ok, Edit configurations -> Before launch: Remote external tool does that. Closed.

Comment: @Dormidont, I tried what you suggested and it worked. Can you move your answer from the comment to the answer section and mark it as the best answer? That way it'll be clear what the solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, as per comment above:

PyCharm has its helper script to run nose tests. I configured the interpreter to be remote python and now I get this (which is what I need): ssh://xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22/path/to/bin/python -u /path/to/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/noserunner.py /path/to/test_elf.py .

Now I just need to figure out pre-test scripts that are usually sourced from .bashrc.
Edit configurations -> Before launch: Remote external tool does that

Answer (score 3):

I found that if you pass `-u` first in the "Interpreter Options" then it passes that parameter to the interpreter (python) as opposed to the library so I find that 

`/opt/conda/bin/python -u -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=4 your_script.py`

works, while

`/opt/conda/bin/python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=4 -u your_script.py`

does not.

Note that if you pass `-u` explicitly, it doesn't add it again later in the command.

Answer (score 1):

[According to IntelliJ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000044644-PyCharm-remove-python-u-option-with-remote-interpreter?page=1#community_comment_360000038310) the `-u` flag is "hardcoded" and there's no way to remove it.

**UPDATE**

IntelliJ currently has an [open ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-28339) for this.